# Запятая в предложении с "как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Есть предложение:

> Глупо просто дать им подохнуть, если
> повезет, сможем получить выкуп или
> продать(,) как рабов.

Мне предлагают поставить запятую в указанном месте. На мой взгляд, она там лишняя, я не знаю правила, по которому она там нужна. Рассудите, плиз.

Прим. Это не сравнение, это действительно предложение о продаже в рабство (фентези-рассказ). Т.е. "как" в значении "в качестве", а не "словно"

Answer (score 2):

> Это не сравнение, это действительно предложение о продаже в рабство

Ну так получается, что Вы знаете правило хотя бы в общих чертах. Конечно же, не нужна запятая, если "как" используется в значении "в качестве".

Впрочем, я отчасти могу понять требовавшего тут запятой, если по его мнению подразумевается какая-то особая авторская интонация: например "сможем получить выкуп или продать, [продать] как рабов" -  т.е. с паузой на месте подразумевающегося повтора. Но в данном случае даже при таком понимании ставить запятую очень не рекомендуется, это вводит в заблуждение, т.к. запятая перед "как" (без существенной перестройки фразы) означала бы именно сравнение, а совсем не усилительную функцию.